# Are these regions subsets of one another?

Tags: inequality

Assume we have a region defined by a relationship between three variables as follows

$$R_1: |x|^2 +2\big|\ xz-|y|^2\big| \leq |y|^2$$

Also assume we have another relationship as follows

$$R_2: |x|^2 \leq 2|y|^2 \leq |z|^2$$

Can one prove whether these these two regions are subsets of one another, or is it an impossible thing to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be that $R_2\subseteq R_1$ since $R_2$ contains the point $(1,1,9999)$ but $R_1$ does not. Moreover it cannot be that $R_1\subseteq R_2$, with the point $(1,1,1)$ as a witness.

I could have chosen more minimal points, but this describes a pattern one can use to find counterexamples to statements that don't have much obvious symmetry. First consider qualitatively what happens when some variables are "really small" and others are "really big". Then try to assume the variables have very special relationships among them.

(To get the best relationships, it helps to figure out cases where equality might hold in a very special way: for instance one way you could have seen the point $(1,1,1)$ is to ask if equality can hold with one term zero. It can't be the first term because $0+2|0+|y|^2|>|y|^2$ unless [etc], but it could be the second term if all are real and $xz=y^2$)

Comment: Thanks, could it be that they have an intersection of point?

Comment: @Henry: Of a single point? That would be hard to answer. But if all you want is that the intersection is nonempty, this can be done (pretty easily) by using the pattern I describe in the post. [Once again, though, if this was a question you were interested in, you **really** should have put it in the original post.]

Comment: Sorry yes I meant can one find an intersection between the two regions..

Comment: (Hm, I guess a single point would only be hard to answer if it were true, which I suspect it's not in this case. If it's false you just have to find two points, or a point on the interior of the intersection.)